# Magento 2 braintree paypal is not working getting null response

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, payment, paypal, braintree

Magento 2.3.5 version using

when pay amount with Braintree PayPal then getting this error on the response from this URL - http://127.0.0.1/dummy/braintree/paypal/review/

Getting this error -

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger::debug() must be
        of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/dummy/vendor/magento/module-braintree/Controller/Paypal/Review.php on line 69 and defined in
     /var/www/html/dummy/vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/Method/Logger.php:51 Stack trace:
     #0 /var/www/html/dummy/vendor/magento/module-braintree/Controller/Paypal/Review.php(69): 
    Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger->debug(NULL) #1 
    /var/www/html/dummy/generated/code/Magento/Braintree/Controller/Paypal/Review/Interceptor.php
    (24): Magento\Braintree\Controller\Paypal\Review->execute() #2 /var/www/html/dummy/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(108):
     Magento\Braintree\Controller\Paypal\Review\Interceptor->execute() #3 
    /var/www/html/dummy/vendor/magento/module-braintree/Controller/Paypal/AbstractAction.php(66):
     Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #4 
    /var/www/html/dummy/vendor/magento/framework/
    in /var/www/html/dummy/vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/Method/Logger.php on line 51
```

Also, there is a git issue but the solution is not there - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23719

The Paypal popup is open and I am able to pay but the response is coming null.
Anyone know please how to solve this ?

Note - I am able to pay via Braintree credit card